# Tag: "finance-data" or just "finance"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have 10 questions with the tag [finance-data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance-data).
There is no tag [finance](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance).

Is it on purpose?
Would it be a good idea or a bad idea to rename the tag from [finance-data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance-data) to just [finance](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that [finance](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) is better than [finance-data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance-data). If there are no objections, we can rename the tag.

Comment: The question is whether or not tags are used for searches across Stack Exchange areas.  If so, then finance-data is better.

Comment: @Jeanne The problem is that we could append the -data to half of the tags we have, e.g. [tag:government-data], [tag:census-data] or [tag:geospatial-data]. That just doesn't feel right.